# read excel file on onedrive 365 with python

Tags: python, onedrive

I just want to read an excel file which located on Onedrive 365.

I read a lot of ressources on the web but nothing works !!!

My actual code is

```
from office365.runtime.auth.authentication_context import AuthenticationContext
from office365.sharepoint.client_context import ClientContext
from office365.sharepoint.file import File 

url = 'https://yoursharepointsite.com/sites/documentsite'
username = 'yourusername'
password = 'yourpassword'
relative_url = '/sites/documentsite/Documents/filename.xlsx'
```

---

```
import io
import pandas as pd

response = File.open_binary(ctx, relative_url)

#save data to BytesIO stream
bytes_file_obj = io.BytesIO()
bytes_file_obj.write(response.content)
bytes_file_obj.seek(0) #set file object to start

#read file into pandas dataframe
df = pd.read_excel(bytes_file_obj)
```

I have the following error

```
out>>> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'web'
```

Do you have an idea ?

Comment: Have you tried `pip install web` ?

Comment: yes i tried and i have the following message : "Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement web (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for web"

Comment: Well the problem is that module. So you will either have to find a version that works or use something that doesn't depend on it. The PyPI entry for `web` makes it look like it is not supposed to be used for anything.

Comment: Are you using python3 or python2 here? I'm unable to import the `AuthenticationContext` on Python3 because it uses `urlparse`. In python3 this module is accessible via `from urlib.parse import urlparse`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to authenticate first and then use the connector to return the file:

```
from office365.runtime.auth.user_credential import UserCredential
from office365.sharepoint.client_context import ClientContext

site_url = "https://yoursharepointsite.com" + f"/sites/{documentsite}/"
ctx = ClientContext(site_url).with_credentials(
    UserCredential(username, password=password))
ctx.load(ctx.web)
ctx.execute_query()

from office365.sharepoint.files import file
import io

file_url = file_dl if dynamic else f'/sites/{documentsite}/{file_dl}'
response = file.File.open_binary(ctx, file_url)
bytes_file_obj = io.BytesIO()
bytes_file_obj.write(response.content)
bytes_file_obj.seek(0)
return bytes_file_obj
```